# ZXing-Core BitMatrix to BitMap

Tags: c#, bitmap, asp.net-core, zxing

I am using **ZXing-Core(0.14.0.2)** to create a barcode which gives me a BitMatrix, however I have not found documentation as to how to extract the image part from the **BitMatrix** and use it as **BitMap** so I can incorporate in my bigger image. Eventually what I would like to end up with would be something like this:

[image: White Image With Barcode at the bottom]

The code I currently have is:

```
img = new Bitmap(300, 375);
drawing = Graphics.FromImage(img);
var barCode = new Code128Writer().encode(packageModel.TrackingId.PrintValue, BarcodeFormat.CODE_128, 280, 70);
src = transform **barCode** to **Drawing.Image**
drawing.DrawImage(src, new Rectangle(10, 255, 280, 70));
```

**UPDATE**
I now have this code, however I am getting an error **You have to set a renderer instance.** I dont understand why the interface is not instantiating this class by itself. There is not documentation available revealing how this is supposed to work. I cant use the **Write** functions because the Rendering is set to null, however I am not sure how to instantiate it.

```
IBarcodeWriterGeneric<Image> barcodeWriterGeneric = new BarcodeWriterGeneric<Image>
{

      Format = BarcodeFormat.CODE_128,
      Options = new EncodingOptions
      {
            Width = 280,
            Height = 70
      },
      Renderer = new PixelData() //HOW DOES THE RENDERER WORK????
};

var test = barcodeWriterGeneric.Write("WORKS");
drawing.DrawImage(test, new Rectangle(10, 255, 280, 70));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see the ZXing-Core fork is missing the PixelDataRenderer class. It contains only the RawRenderer. You should switch to the original ZXing.Net package with the current version 0.15.0. That one contains the barcode writer class "BarcodeWriterPixelData" which does the necessary initialization of the Renderer property. Next version of ZXing.Net will contain some more specialized bindings to other .Net Core compatible imaging libraries like CoreCompat.System.Drawing, ImageSharp, OpenCV and more. With that bindings you can then generate other output formats besides PixelData.

Comment: After cloning down the ZXing-Core repo I came to the same conclusion, there are key classes missing from the ZXing-Core package. I have been pulling my hair for the past couple of hours. I'll try to use the ZXIng.Net package but I am not sure if I will be able to install it in my Web API core project. Thank you for the answer this confirms my suspicions.

Comment: Version 0.16.0 of ZXing.Net is available. There is a special nuget package available which supports CoreCompat.System.Drawing directly.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net.Bindings.CoreCompat.System.Drawing/
You can now use the class ZXing.CoreCompat.System.Drawing.BitmapWriter.

Answer (score 2):

Create a renderer that implements `IBarcodeRenderer<TOut>`. This one works for me in iOS.

```
var writer = new BarcodeWriter<UIImage>()
{
    Format = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.CODE_128,
    Options = new EncodingOptions
    {
        Height = height,
        Width = width,
        Margin = 0
    },
    Renderer = new BarcodeRenderer()
};

var image = writer.Write(barcodeValue);



private class BarcodeRenderer : IBarcodeRenderer<UIImage>
{
    public UIImage Render(BitMatrix matrix, ZXing.BarcodeFormat format, string content)
    {
        return RenderMatrix(matrix);
    }

    public UIImage Render(BitMatrix matrix, ZXing.BarcodeFormat format, string content, EncodingOptions options)
    {
        return RenderMatrix(matrix);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Renders the bitmatrix.
/// </summary>
private static UIImage RenderMatrix(BitMatrix matrix)
{
    var width = matrix.Width;
    var height = matrix.Height;

    var black = new CGColor(0f, 0f, 0f);
    var white = new CGColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(new CGSize(width, height));
    var context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();

    for (var x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        for (var y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            context.SetFillColor(matrix[x, y] ? black : white);
            context.FillRect(new CGRect(x, y, 1, 1));
        }
    }

    var img = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphics.EndImageContext();

    return img;
}
```